# Unable to load css and js properly while using mod_proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have done the configuration of `mod_proxy` with httpd in the redhat linux server environment.
I was able to access the projects as we have discussed, but unable to access the content in it properly.

On looking at the logs, it says that:

> [Fri Sep 27 18:57:58 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does
>   not exist: /var/www/html/css, referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/abc

Comment: We're really going to need a lot more information than this: What are the relevant lines from your configuration? What requests are you sending? Where are the files really located?